# How to select checkbox on the basis of textbox values seperated by comma in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to select the checkbox based on the id passes in textbox seperated by comma (,) like (1,2,3,..).
How can we acheive this in jquery?

```js
function cblist_check() {

  if ($('input[type=text][id$=rate]').val() != "") {
    var arrate = $('input[type=text][id$=rate]').val().split(',');
    for (var i in arrate) {
      $('[id$=listRates] input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked")

    }

  }

}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative;'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='1' data-display-name='Rack/General' />
  <label for='1'>Rack/General</label>
  <img id='img_1' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
</div>
<div style='position:relative;'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='4' data-display-name='Government' />
  <label for='4'>Government</label>
  <img id='img_4' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
</div>
<div style='position:relative;'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='6' data-display-name='Package' />
  <label for='6'>Package</label>
  <img id='img_6' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
</div>
<div style='position:relative;'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='3' data-display-name='Family' />
  <label for='3'>Family</label>
  <img id='img_3' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over array and set checked individually. You can use `.map()` function to get all elements and then set them checked all at once:

```
var arrate = $('input[type=text][id$=rate]').val().split(',');
var targetcheckboxes =$.map( arrate, function(i) { return document.getElementById(i) } );
$(targetcheckboxes).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Its working but only once means when page gets load first time.
What should be a possible solution? I want it to be worked on every click.
Please update.

Comment: @RahulHendawe: you need to write the code on click event.

Comment: Yes I called cblist_check() function on onclick, but Its not working properly.

Comment: @RahulHendawe: please create fiddle and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to concatenate the value with the # selector,

```
 var arrate = $('input[type=text][id$=rate]').val().split(',');
 for (var i in arrate) {
   $('#' + arrate[i]).prop("checked",true)
 }
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m1h3rtLd/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function cblist_check() {
    var s = ',' + $('input[type=text][id$=rate]').val() + ',';
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, x){
        $(x).prop("checked", s.indexOf(',' + $(x).attr('id') + ',') > -1);
    });
}
```